# html5/css3 navbar sizing issue

Tags: html, css, nav

Haven't done any web design for a while now but my girlfriend needed a stack of updates to her site which I did a few years back and have kind of been adding to bit by bit, and as a result it's kind of patchy, so I figured I'd look into all the newer developments and try a complete overhaul with a bit of responsive design thrown in for various devices.

i'm just having a specific issue with the main template page I'm constructing - I've put a copy up here:

http://massagecamden.co.uk/copy2/index.html

Anyway, I know there are a lot of things to be dealt with in terms of media query specifics for the different sized pages, but my current problem is to do with the width of my navigation bar on the desktop size version.

I was plugging away thinking it looked great on one monitor and then dragged it over to a larger one and lo and behold, the nav bar is is sticking to the left of the gridContainer div.
I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 here for the fluid layouts and the nav bar itself is inside a fluid div called navigation which has its width set to 100%.

Now the header image above it is also in a fluid div (called header) with its width also set to 100%.
Before I noticed the nav problem I was having problems with getting the image centred until I came across a question (on here I think) which lead me to the solution of creating a display:block rule for the img and then using the margin:auto trick to center it.

However this  (or anything else I've tried) doesn't seem to work on the nav bar.
I admit i took a most of the construction from a number of tutorials on the web but I am quite proud of the result - if only I could get it to size/position properly when I expand the browser width?

Ideally I'd like it to remain a static size similar to the header image and to be centred similarly too. If this was doable I'd also then like to be able to see more of the background image at the sides too, like in the original home page at http://massagecamden.co.uk/ but I relise the margin:auto on the gridContainer probably won't do this by virtue of the fluid grid?

Anyone got any ideas where I'm going wrong?
Please?

many thanks
Craig.

Comment: If possible, pull out the relevant CSS and markup and make an isolated example on http://www.jsfiddle.net and place the CSS/HTML here also. This way the question may provide benefit to others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will center the nav.

```
#navigation {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what else you're trying to do.

Comment: Fantastic! Right first time! I posted this at 6am and had been working on this TOO long! I think I was getting confused re the difference between the navigation div and the new nav html5 tag. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do this:

```
#navigation {
    width: 100%; /* You said you have done this already */
}

#header { /* Image is here */
    width: 1000px; /* For example */
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

You have to set #header's width, because otherwise it won't be centered.

I'm not sure you meant this, but hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - maybe i wasn't too clear - I'm trying to center the nav element (nav bar essentially) on the larger browser settings.

Comment: Thanks you to clearing the answer and sorry about I didn't get your point. If @MarkRyanSallee's answer was right (and I think you think it is), accept it by clicking accept-button under the answer's vote buttons.